# which way would be best practice to design html5 website?

Tags: html

I have this type of basic design:

```
+--------+-------------------------+
|        |                         |
|        |                         |
|        |                         |
|        |                         |
|        |                         |
|        |                         |
|        |                         |
|        |                         |
+--------+-------------------------+
```

What's the best practice to design it with html5?

```
<aside>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
</aside>
<aside>
   <main></main>
</aside>
```

Or,

```
<header>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
</header>
<aside>
   <main></main>
</aside>
```

Or, something else?

Comment: I don't see any header in your layout also, it `aside` is generally used for sidebar

Comment: first: contains 3-4 types menu items and second: contains article items

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking about the problem backwards. Semantic HTML begins with content rather than the layout. You should start by evaluating your content, then use the minimum amount of HTML to represent that content.

The usage of `<aside>` and `<header>` should have nothing to do with where the element appears in your layout.

Based on your comment about the content, it sounds like you have a `<nav>` and possibly a `<main>` containing a list of `<article>`s.

```
<nav>
  <ul class="link-list">
    <li><a>...</a></li>
    <li><a>...</a></li>
    <li><a>...</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<main>
  <ul class="article-list">
    <article>...</article>
    <article>...</article>
    <article>...</article>
  </ul>
</main>
```